Как повернуть объект через кватернион если можно использовать только вектор/матрицу
У меня есть кватернион и у меня есть объект который нужно повернуть. Но объект не поддерживаем кватернион для поворотов. Он может использовать для этого матрицу 4 на 4 и/или vec3. Как преобразовать кватернион в mat4/vec3? Я использую OpenGL 4.6, glm и при передачи
информации в шейдер я 3 аргументом указываю GL_FALSE.
Вот пример кода:
// из btQuaternion в glm::quat
glm::quat q = glm::quat(btQuat.w(), btQuat.x(), btQuat.y(), btQuat.z());

// пытаюсь вращать
glm::mat4 rotate = glm::mat4(1.0f) * glm::mat4_cast(q);

UPD1: Мне нужно управлять человеком/машиной и т.д на поверхности, версия для порядка самолётом может не подойти.
UPD2: Тело вращается по мировому пространству физического движка Bullet Physics и вращение преобразовывается в пространство OpenGL (правда пока безуспешно, код описанный выше не работает, при вращении тело то поднимается над землёй, то опускается под землю). Матрица объекта задаётся вот так:
// matModel - результат действий преобразования из bullet в opengl
// translate - позиция тела, rotate - вращение тела, scaling -
// размер тела и всё это тип glm::mat4
matModel = translate * rotate * scale;
// но, дело в том, что если убрать rotate, то тело перестаёт
// подниматься и опускаться
// matModel = translate * scale; // оно движется нормально, только нет поворотов

А также, кватернион задаёт вращение по осям используемые bullet и объект надо вращать по всем заданным bullet осям. Я их к сожалению не контролирую.
Примечание:
По изображению видно что 1 шар парит над землёй, а второй внутри её.


Ваш код выглядит нормально. В чём проблема?

Проблема в том, что при вращении тела то поднимаются над землёй, то опускаются свозь неё. Дело точно во вращении, так как при его отключении тела перестают себя так вести. Возможно проблема в порядке умножения матриц. У меня порядок такой: матрица = позиция * вращение * размер. Может в этом дело?

Возможно. Не могу сказать точно. Добавьте в вопрос что задаёт кватернион (в каких осях вращение?), как надо вращать объект (в каких осях?), как задана матрица объекта. Лучше если это будет работающие код.

Добавил, скоро и картинку добавлю.

Всё, теперь есть и фото ошибки

Как матрица на вектор умножается? Mv или vM?

Попробуй scale * rotate * translate.

Матрица чего? Позиции, поворота или размера?

Сейчас попробую

Нет, теперь они появляются над землей.

Выставь единичный scale, нулевой translate, меняй только rotate. Как движется шар на экране?

Станислав, если ты не против, можешь пойти в дискорд? Это не обязательно, а ответ обязательно здесь опубликую.

Я не умею в дискорд. Умею в телеграм, зум, гугл мит.

Ок, а у меня нету ничего из перечисленого.

Я в дискорде. stanislavvolodarskiy

Всё, кинул запрос

Всё, проблема решена. Она была из-за того что в 3д модели была смещена центральная точка. Код описанный в самом начале верный.
